# Degree of the formulas for arithmetic sequence

Tags: polynomials

If we have $f(x)$ as a polynomial and $g(x) = f(1) +f(2) + \cdots + f(x)$ and x is any positive integer, I observed that the degree of $g(x)$ is always $1$ higher than the degree of $f(x)$. The only explanation I can think of is this:

If we think of $g(x)$ as $f(x-a) + f(x-b) + \cdots + f(x)$, there will be $x$ number of $x ^ n$ where $n$ is the highest degree of $f(x)$. Thus, summing it up, it simplifies to $x ^ {n + 1}$. I really do feel that something is off with this, can someone please help me?

Comment: What's $f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(x)$ supposed to mean?

Comment: @Gae. S. the sum from f(1) to f(x)

Comment: What's "to $f(x)$" supposed to mean?

Comment: if x is 3 its 1,2,3 if x is 7, its 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Comment: And what if $x$ is *not* $7$, or any other natural number?

Comment: oohh im so sorry, my mistake, x is must be a positive integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Faulhaber's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) shows that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^p$ is a polynomial of $n$ of degree $p+1$. It follows that if $f(x) = \sum_{j=0}^p a_j x^j$ is a polynomial of degree $p$, then $\sum_{k=1}^n f(k)$ is a polynomial of $n$ of degree $p+1$.